# Can I get a list of required packages to install libvips, libvips-dev, libvips-tools for version 8.14.4?

Tags: go, image-processing, image-conversion, vips, libvips

I'm trying to install libvips (https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/tag/v8.14.4) on a alpine distribution of Linux. Can I please get help with list of required packages? I want to get https://github.com/h2non/bimg working on my golang project but build is failing due to missing packages required for libvips. Worked on Mac with straight forward installation instructions.

Comment: Doesn't the package manager already provides the dependencies? See https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/vips

Comment: Yeah, was able to install through this. Thanks